Unable to specify weight in Composable with no Column declared in it
I am trying to build a simple calculator using jetpack compose, my composables are:

calculator(): this composable composes the whole calculator
calculatorRow(): it creates a Row of Buttons

When I apply a Modifier.weight to each Row it doesnt compile because the Column is declared in a different Composable function.
How can I solve this issue?
@Composable
fun calculatorRow(weight: Float, symbols: List<String>, operate: (String) -> Unit) {
    Row(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        Modifier.weight(weight)
    ) {
        symbols.map { symbol ->
            Button(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .padding(1.dp)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)),
                onClick = {
                    operate(symbol)
                }
            ) {
                Text(text = symbol)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun calculator(padding: PaddingValues) {
    var operations = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val operate =
        { word: String -> if (word == "C") operations.value = "" else operations.value += word }
    Column(
        Modifier
            .padding(padding)
    ) {
        Card {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(5.dp),
                text = operations.value
            )
        }
        calculatorRow(1f, listOf("1", "2", "3", "+"), operate)
        calculatorRow(1f, listOf("4", "5", "6", "-"), operate)
        calculatorRow(1f, listOf("7", "8", "9", "*"), operate)
        calculatorRow(1f, listOf("0", ".", "C", "/"), operate)

    }
}


@Preview
@Composable
fun preview() {
    calculator(PaddingValues(10.dp))
}


that's the expected behaviour because calculatorRow Composeable could be called from any other composable function even the funs that u can't use weight in the(exp:Box)
so instead you can pass a modifier to calculatorRow and use it to pass the weight from the right place (the columnScope) in order for it to be compiled.
@Composable
fun calculator(padding: PaddingValues) {
    var operations = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val operate =
        { word: String -> if (word == "C") operations.value = "" else 
    operations.value += word }
        Column(
        Modifier
            .padding(padding)
    ) {
        Card {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(5.dp),
                text = operations.value
            )
        }
        calculatorRow(
            symbols = listOf("1", "2", "3", "+"),
           operate = operate,
           modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
        )
        calculatorRow(
            symbols = listOf("4", "5", "6", "-"),
            operate = operate,
           modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
        )
        calculatorRow(
            symbols = listOf("7", "8", "9", "*"),
            operate = operate,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
        )
       calculatorRow(
            symbols = listOf("0", ".", "C", "/"),
            operate = operate,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
        )

    }
}




@Composable
fun calculatorRow(
    modifier: Modifier,
    symbols: List<String>,
    operate: (String) -> Unit,
) {
    Row(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        symbols.map { symbol ->
            Button(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .padding(1.dp),
                onClick = {
                    operate(symbol)
                }
            ) {
                Text(text = symbol)
            }
        }
    }
}

